# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3k}{k^2+k} \sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k}$

Tags: calculus, divergent-series

I'm having a hard time doing this problem. As this is homework, I'd appreciate a guidance towards a solution, not a full answer. Thanks in advance.

I need to prove that the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3k}{k^2+k} \sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k}$$**converges**. I've found that since

$$\frac{3k}{k^2+k} \sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k} \leq \frac{3}{k}\sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k}=3\sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k^3}$$

we see that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3k}{k^2+k} \sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty 3\sqrt\frac{\ln(k)}{k^3}$$

this is the best approximation I've managed to do, while the series still being convergent, but can't find a way to prove it. I'd love some feedback on whether my approximation is prudent and/or how to proceed towards a solution.

Comment: Note that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, we have $1-\frac{1}{x} \leq \ln (x) \leq \frac{x^2}{2}$.

Comment: I am not sure that the series diverges. You can show that $\ln k<\sqrt k$ in the limit $k\to\infty$. If you want to prove divergence, in this case you need to say that your terms are greater than the terms of a series that goes to $+\infty$

Comment: Thank you guys, esp. @KStarGamer. With that approximation I was easily able to find a convergent majorant series, thus solving the problem.

Comment: @elaia Happy to help- if interested in a proof of that inequality, see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Upper_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm).

Comment: Also @elaia you say you want to prove the series diverges, but the series in fact converges- typo?

Comment: @KStarGamer thanks for the link, will definitely take a look. As you said, that is a clear typo as the series converges. It is also in a clear conflict with the heading, but sometimes not being a native and skipping proofreading backfires :D